# How to read stdout immediately in Python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to make two python processes.

**main.py**

```
child = Popen(['python.exe', 'test.py'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
stdout, stderr = child.communicate(input='hello world'.encode())
result = stdout.decode()
print(result)
```

**test.py**

```
value = sys.stdin.read()
sys.stdout.write(value)
time.sleep(10)
```

(time.sleep is just an example of a time consuming task.)

In this situation, `main.py` waits 10 seconds for `test.py` to end before printing.

Is there a way to print stdout from `test.py` immediately after `sys.stdout.write`?

Comment: In `test.py` you will need to do `sys.stdout.flush()` after the write. (If you don't do this, there is nothing you can do in `main.py` to work around that.)

Comment: In any case, if you do not want to wait, do not read using `communicate` because that will wait for the child to complete - use `child.stdout.read(size)` or `child.stdout.readline()` or similar.

Comment: @alaniwi I tried `sys.stdout.flush()`, but it didn't work. Still had to wait 10 seconds.

Comment: @alaniwi Actually, I am using `communicate` because I am trying to open the `test.py` process once and send tasks to it multiple times.

Comment: See the answer I have now posted -- you can use `communicate`, but only at the end to read any remaining output.  You shouldn't try to do it with each task.  When you use `communicate`, it will wait for subprocess completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example for you where you read and write to the child several times (as you stated in a comment under the question).

The subprocess (`test.py`) will:

- read a line
- convert each one to upper case, and write it back,
- sleep 2 seconds
- repeat until no more input, and then write a final line

The main process (`main.py`) will:

- three times:

  - write a line of input to the subprocess
  - read the answer and say how long it took to get the answer back
  - sleep 5 seconds
- at the end, read any final output using `communicate`, and report this

Here is the output of the code that is shown below:

```
writing to child: hello world 0
child replied with: HELLO WORLD 0
got answer back within 0.00022 seconds

writing to child: hello world 1
child replied with: HELLO WORLD 1
got answer back within 0.00012 seconds

writing to child: hello world 2
child replied with: HELLO WORLD 2
got answer back within 0.00021 seconds

final output from child: finishing
```

And here is the code:

`test.py`

```
import sys
import time

while True:
    value = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not value:
        break
    sys.stdout.write(value.upper())
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(2)

sys.stdout.write("finishing\n")
```

`main.py`

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import time

child = Popen(['python.exe', 'test.py'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
time.sleep(1)

for i in range(3):
    data_in = f"hello world {i}"
    print(f"writing to child: {data_in}")

    time0 = time.time()
    child.stdin.write(f"{data_in}\n".encode())
    child.stdin.flush()
    data_out = child.stdout.readline()
    time1 = time.time()
    
    result = data_out.decode().strip()
    elapsed_time = time1 - time0
    print(f"child replied with: {result}")
    print(f"got answer back within {elapsed_time:.5f} seconds\n")
    time.sleep(5)

output, error = child.communicate()
print(f"final output from child: {output.decode()}")
```

*(Tested on Linux using `python` instead of `python.exe` - hopefully it will work equally on Windows although I can't test this.)*

As you can see, the answer is received without having to wait for the `sleep` to complete.

(Obviously if the sleep time in the parent is reduced to below about 2 seconds, then the child would not be ready to receive the data when it is sent, so then there would be more of a wait to get an answer back.)

With this sort of two-way communication, it is very easy to end up in a deadlock situation (each process is waiting for the other to do something).  To avoid that, each process writes exactly one line each time, ensuring that it ends with a newline, and immediately flushes the output buffer -- and the reading process uses `readline()` to read exactly one line (reads until newline).  Then hopefully the two should remain in step and avoid deadlocks.